# useRef - use ref to handler function inside functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do you pass / use refs inside a handler function inside a functional component?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function RegisterUser() {
  const emailInput = useRef(null);
  const passwordInput = useRef(null);

  const handleClickRegister = () => {
    RegisterPersonMutation(email, password, callbackValue => {
      emailInput.current.value = ''; // <---------------------this guy
      passwordInput.current.value = ''; // <------------------and his friend
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="register-wrap">
      <form>
        <input type="text" ref={emailInput} />
        <input type="password" ref={passwordInput} />
      </form>
      <button onClick={() => handleClickRegister()}>Register</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegisterUser;
```

Comment: You do it just the way you do it in your code. What's the problem?

Comment: Why you need to pass useRefs inside a handle instead useState for handling the state

Comment: @codemonkey Actually... I realized I left out one layer. It's being used inside the RegisterPersonMutation, which is one level deeper. I updated my OP.

Comment: That should also work. Are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: @codemonkey I should actually just be using useState like FrankSiret said, but in my example I get `can't read value current of undefined`

Comment: Why you are not using controlled component ?

Comment: It depends on your situation, but `useRef` is a perfectly viable option. I am just shocked that it gives you that error in that context. It should work just fine. I'm wondering if you're omitting some stuff to simplify your question and thus leave out important details.

Comment: it may be that the variable has not initialized

Comment: use useEffect for checking that

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to know how to create and use refs inside nested functions using `useRef`... but in this case, Frank was right in that I should just use `useState`.

I'm already using it in my real component so it's like this:

```
function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  handleClick(foo, bar, callback => {
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
  });

  <input value={email} />
  <input value={password} />

}
```